# View what to delete before taking action

Tags: vim

With Vim editor, before deleting lines or words, I'd like to view what I delete before committing a big mistake. Could anyone have an idea how could it possible to do that? Is there exist a command-line for that? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: You can use a visual selection (`V`) to highlight the text and delete the selection.

Comment: This is Vim. You can press `u` to undo. And if you have undofiles enabled, you can undo even if you save and quit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@ThomasDickey wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332451/view-what-to-delete-before-taking-action/332478#comment585095_332451) there's a visual mode that you can enter by pressing <kbd>v</kbd>. This starts selection. After entering visual mode you can move the cursor around to select the extent of the text you want to delete. If you then press <kbd>x</kbd> it will delete everything selected, including the character under the cursor, and exit visual mode.

You can exit visual mode at any time by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

You can enter visual *block* mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. This enables you to delete a rectangular block of text, or to insert (using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>) into multiple lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing a global search and replace, such as

```
:%s/replaceme/withthis/g
```

Then you may tag on a `c` (for "confirm"):

```
:%s/replaceme/withthis/gc
```

This will ask for confirmation for each occurance of `replaceme` before carrying out the substitution.